# Source of IP address

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, netplan, ip

Probably a noob question, but I need some help in trying to determine where an IP address originates from.

So I have a Raspberry 4 with Ubuntu 20.10 installed. I've initially configured a static IP address using netplan, first disabled the default cloud init like this

```
sudo nano /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg
network: {config: disabled}
```

I then created this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Added this content:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.10.50/24
      gateway4: 192.168.10.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

This worked like a charm.

Afterwards I discovered Cockpit for managing multiple servers, but it had the requirement for using `NetworkManager` instead of `networkd`. So I changed the line `renderer: NetworkManager`.

This also works like a charm... but the funny thing is that my machine is now also picking up a DHCP address every time and for the life of me, I have no idea where this configuration originates from. I've used nmtui and tried to set the interface from automatic to manual, but it get's reset to automatic after a reboot.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Apparently adding "`{config: disabled}`" to the file "`99-disable-network-config.cfg`" is not all there's to do. The default file in `/etc/netplan` still exists and is merged during "`sudo netplan apply`", hence my static and DHCP address. Once I deleted the default file, all is good.

Hope this helps someone.